Error with force_tz () with unused arguments
I tried the following command:
d <- "2015-01-01 09:00"
timezone <- "America/Santiago"
force_tz(time=ymd_hm(d), tzone=timezone)

and get the following error message:
Error in force_tz(time = ymd_hm(d), tzone = timezone) : 
  unused arguments (time = ymd_hm(d), tzone = timezone)

Further details:
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.4.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: America/Los_Angeles
tzcode source: internal

lubridate version ‘1.9.3’

I tried different time zones as well as to uninstall and reinstall lubridate but nothing works so far ...
Any ideas why this happens or a workaround?

Yeah, that looks weird. I know you're intending to be using lubridate::force_tz, can you confirm that that is what is actually being used? Just type in the function name force_tz and hit enter, it should end with <environment: namespace:lubridate>. If it is something else, then you have identified a conflict. (You can also do lubridate::force_tz(time=ymd_hm(d), tzone=timezone) to see if forcing the package namespace fixes the error, still pointing to the same likely problem.) (BTW, on ubuntu-23.10 and R-4.3.2 and lubridate-1.9.3, I do not get that error ...)

Thank you so much for the quick reply!
I tried the same code in RStudio and it worked. I then switched back to Visual Studio Code and got this error message. I was able to solve the problem by uninstalling and reinstalling lubridate by using the "Install CRAN Package" under the R extension menu instead of using "install.packages()" in the terminal.
It finally works!

Wow, that's an obscure bug, I'm now really curious how VSCode was resolving the function and how VS chooses to install packages. That seems rather ... concerning.
